# lg ms770 touch screen unresponsive

Tags: touchscreen

i really hope i can get solution to my dilemma..
quick details: my phone (lgms770) fell (had its protective case) and now i cannot swipe to unlock, answer phone calls, text..basically the touch screen does not respond. This has never happened before. The power button does work though. It has fallen many times but it always ended up responding well. I removed the case, the battery the sim card and left it for a couple minutes.Then I put everything back together (for several times now) and restarted the phone, but the screen is still not responding. Is there any way to fix this without having to get a new phone??